# Can the content (inc. timestamps and author) of Github Issues be counted on?

Tags: github, privacy, github-issues, audit

I'm aware that the timestamps for Github repos as seen on github.com/* are based on the timestamps [provided by the editor's machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253643/632951), thus cannot be counted on. (This seems to be the case as well for Wikis.)

But for Issues/discussions, can the timestamps and content be counted on?

While it's true an Issue could be deleted entirely, it seems that as long as it is shown, then the contents can be counted as trustworthy, to the point where when users choose to delete their past content (scrubbing off history), the timestamp is not removed even if the delete action itself is not timestamped.

Is this true? Does the Github API provide a "backdoor" for editors?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294503/github-issues-closed-date-is-before-created-date-how-is-it-possible